# Chrome web audio api - how to play sound in a phone call

Tags: android, google-chrome, audio, web-audio-api

I cant find anything online but how can i use a chrome tab web audio api in an android app so i can play sound during a phone call.

i went to this [site](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/MIDIDrums/index.html) but when i play the sound during a phone call the far end doens't here anything.  I thought one feature of web audio was that it can play change the sound of someones voice in a phone call, so i thought it had access to the audio phone call stream.

even [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/10/Web-Audio-live-audio-input---now-on-Android?hl=en) the tech says its ready for android but i cant even get hte audio recorder demo to work on android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you do (with the user permission) have access to the input of the device you only have access to the main output of the device (internal speakers or headphones). This is represented as the AudioContext.destination. The buffers in a call is (probably) a different output that you simply don't have access to in Web Audio (and that's probably a good thing. Imagine the security issues we'd have if apps were allowed to hijack calls!).